# Install JDK with apt-get on ubuntu precise 64

Tags: java, ubuntu

I'm trying to install Java JDK 8 with this instruction:

```
apt-get update -y
apt-get install -y python-software-properties
add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
apt-get update -y
apt-get install -y  oracle-java8-installer
```

but I get a 404 while I'm running last command:

> Connecting to download.oracle.com
>   (download.oracle.com)|95.101.180.41|:80... connected. HTTP request
>   sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found 2017-10-18 10:33:03 ERROR
>   404: Not Found.
>
> download failed

How many days since this problems happens? It is strange a 404 for a Java installer. Isnt'it? Any workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to install java 8 manually.
Just download java (tar.gz) from oracle site.

Then, create directory for your jdk like (of course if folder doesn't exist)

```
$/opt/jdk
```

and extract java into created folder.

```
$tar -zxf jdk-8u152-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /opt/jdk
```

Then, it is very important, to set it as the default JVM in your machine run.
Just use that command:

```
$update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_152/bin/java 100
```

and

```
$update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_152/bin/javac 100
```

Now, verify that java installed correctly.

```
$java -version
```

Answer (score 0):

A new SDK version is out and the old version is no longer available. Wait for a updated package, install manually or use OpenJDK.